# Get time if today else get date MYSQL timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, date

In a table I have timestamp column. The time in the timestamp looks as shown below.

```
                          2015-08-14 18:07:36
```

To select in format of HH:MM AM/PM I used as shown below

```
               select TIME_FORMAT(timestamp_column, '%h:%i %p') from table_name;
```

What I need?

If the record inserted today(on present day) it have to retrieve timestamp in format of HH:MM AM/PM. If record is inserted on previous days then retrieve the timestamp as DD/MM/YY.

How can I write such a sql query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case when date(timestamp_column) = curdate()
            then TIME_FORMAT(timestamp_column, '%h:%i %p') 
            else DATE_FORMAT(timestamp_column, '%d/%m/%y')
      end
from table_name;
```

Comment: add some text about what you do